# Facebook status updates disappearing from timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have created a simple Facebook Page. Because it is about past events, I backdated each status update to correct date. All was fine, when I was adding (and backdating) events for past year (2013). Once I started to enter status updates for current year, they're all gone. I can't see them (or any for 2014) on my timeline.

Particular status update appears only, if I add it with current date (January 15). When I backdate it for any past date in January (e.g. January 2) it is gone.

I'm pretty sure, that these status update were added, because:

- they appeary in the News Feed (!),
- I am able to create Promote Page ads using newest status updates' content,
- Facebook warns me, when I'm trying to add exactly the same status update as just posted.

But they're all not visible in main page, that is on Timeline of my page.

I tried using different browsers, refreshing page, relogin, anything. No effect.

I can add as many status update as I want, when they're are posted with no date change (current date) or when I backdate them to year 2013. Whenever I post something (I can see it!) and then make its date to any date in 2014, except today -- post update vanishes.

What is wrong or what am I missing?

(I asked [the same](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1396037300650215) question of *Facebook Community*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** have **all** your status updates backdated! You must have *at least one post* with current date!

It goes like this:

- once you backdate your last post with current date, all your post from particular year are hidden from timeline (don't have any idea, why)?
- once you add at least one status update with current date, they're all visible back again.

If you need to have all important posts backdated, then at the end of back-editing your page, post anything with current date, to have everything back in place and easily displayed!

Comment: Brilliant (answer) and stupid (Facebook behavior)! :]

Comment: I just found out, that it works for today and yesterday posts, i.e. if at least one of all status updates has current date or is backdated for yesterday, you'll see all of them. If, on contrary, all posts are backdated in past for earlier than yesterday, then some or all of them may not be visible on Timeline (but are in the News Feed).